# No other King but God....and David?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, malchut-royalty

In The Avinu Malkeinu prayer, it says, "We have no King other than you", what about the House of David/Mashiach?

Comment: if there were no concept of any other king, then how could the torah and nach tell of Hashem's laws for establishing an earthly king? What would "melech malchei hamelachim" mean if there were to be no other human kings? I believe the premise for this question ignores the basic distinction between "melech basar vadam" and "melech ha'olam"

Comment: Could it possibly be a refutation of all the false Kings i.e. Malchus Beis Chashmonai, Hordus, etc.?, as in we have no other King but you (at present until Mashiach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it's speaking only about hashem as an ultimate king from the beginning of the times till the end.

Answer (score 1):

Only G-d is a truly omnipotent king. All other rulers are ultimately under the control of G-d as it says "Lev melachim beyad Hashem"

Comment: So what about the Messiah, is he not the King of Klal Yisroel? "and they will seek HaShem their G-d, and David their King?"  I hate conjecturing on the scriptures, but is it possible that posuk you mentioned is actually going on the Gentile Kings?  --- Without breaking into an entire free will vs. hashgacha/fate discussion ;)